# Delete an element based on the child image name through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I plan on deleting all instances of an entire `<div>` from the page, if it has an image with a specific name. I am not sure if it's even possible with JQuery.

### Here is my HTML:-

```
<div class="jk-content-module__image">
    <a href="#" class="colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-1"></a>

    <a href="path-to-img" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="path-to-img" alt="" title="">
    </a>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="colorbox-inline-1">
            <ul>
                <li class="first last"><a href="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" alt="" title=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am hoping is, that all the `<div>` on my page with a class of `jk-content-module__image` should have the child `<div style="display: none;"> ... </div>` removed, if there is an `<img>` with a src of `blank_0.png` in it.

Hence if the image has a src of `blank_0.png` present, I want the entire `<div style="display: none;">` to be removed.

I hope I am clear.

I'll be grateful if you could assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` on `".jk-content-module__image"` elements with parameter `:has(img[src=blank_0.png])`,  `.find()` with parameter `"div[style*='display: none']"` note space character before `none` which matches current `html`, `.remove()`

```
$(function() {
  $(".jk-content-module__image").filter(":has(img[src*='blank_0.png'])")
  .find("div[style*='display: none']").remove()
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ks6b596n/1/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('img[src~=/blank_0.png]').closest('div[style*="display: none"]').remove();
```

In English: Find all `img` elements who's `src` attributes end in `/blank_0.png`. From there, find their closest ancestor elements who's `style` attributes contain `display: none`. Remove those ancestor elements.

May need to adjust the spacing in `display: none` as this needs to be exactly as it appears in the original.

In javascript:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')).filter(function(e,i,a){
  return e.src.endsWith('/blank_0.png');
}).forEach(function(e,i,a){
  var t = e.parentNode;
  while(t != null && (t.nodeName != 'DIV' || t.style.display != 'none')){
    t = t.parentNode;
  }
  if(t != null && t.parentNode != null) {
    t.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: `.closest('div:hidden')` would be better.

Comment: a class/id to that div will be even better

Comment: @Jai `.closest('div:hidden')` would match on the inner `div` which is not what was wanted. jQuery considers it hidden since it's parent `div` is hidden. See jQuery's docs on [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Comment: @madalinivascu There's no class/id on the target elements as provided by OP.

Comment: @Ouroborus _<div style="display: none;"> ... </div> removed_....seems this is what OP wanted and what your code actually does.

Comment: @Jai Yes, however `.closest('div:hidden')` would match on the inner `div` of `<div style="display: none;"><div id="colorbox-inline-1">...</div></div>` since that's considered the closest hidden div. It counts as hidden because it has a hidden ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elements = $(".jk-content-module__image");
  elements.each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(obj).find("div[style*='display: none'] img").attr("src").indexOf("blank_0.png") > 0) {
      $(obj).find(".hiddenDiv").remove();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jk-content-module__image">
  <a href="#" class="colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-1"></a>

  <a href="path-to-img" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2">
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="path-to-img" alt="" title="">
  </a>
  <div class="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
    <div id="colorbox-inline-1">
      <ul>
        <li class="first last">
          <a href="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" alt="" title="">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used part of it in the upper solution.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this with JQuery?

```
    //get the src for your image
var imgSrc = $(".jk-content-module__image div img").attr('src').toLowerCase()
//see if it contains blank_0
if(imgSrc.indexOf('blank_0.png')>-1)
{
  //if true, remove the div
  $(".jk-content-module__image div")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
$(".jk-content-module__image div:hidden").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('img').attr('src').indexOf('blank_0.png') !== -1
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jk-content-module__image">
  <a href="#" class="colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-1"></a>

  <a href="path-to-img" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2">
  visible image
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="path-to-img" alt="" title="">
  </a>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div id="colorbox-inline-1">
      <ul>
        <li class="first last">
          <a href="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" title="" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-node-2"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://thesite.com/sites/default/files/default_images/blank_0.png" alt="" title=""> hidden img</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odz2h7Lw/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time for this.